# Serverless python requests with long timeouts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, software-design

I have a several python scripts that follow a similar format: you pass in a date, and it either: - checks my S3 bucket for the file with that date in the filename, and parses it or - Runs a python script doing some analysis on the file of that date (which take over 1 hour to run)

I am looking for a serverless solution that would let me call these functions on a range of dates, and run them all in parallel. Because of the long duration of my python script, services like AWS and Google Cloud Functions don't work because of their timeouts (15 minutes and 9 minutes respectively). I have looked at Google Cloud Dataflow, but am not sure whether this is overkill for my relatively simple use case.

Something with the lowest possible outages is important, so I am leaning towards something from AWS, Google Cloud, etc.

I also would like to be able to see a dashboard of the progress of each job with logs, so I can see which dates have completed and which dates had a bug (plus what the bug is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running duration is planned in the Cloud Run roadmap but we don't have date for now.

Today, the best recommended way is to [use AppEngine in addition of Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/). With push queue, you can run process up to 24H long when you deploy in [manual scaling mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed). But Be careful, manual scaling doesn't scale to 0!

If you prefer container, I know 2 "strange" workaround on GCP:

- Use Cloud Build. Cloud Build allows you to [build custom builder in a container](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps). Do whatever you want in this container, even if it's not for building something. Think to [set up the correct timeout for your processing step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2). You have 120 minutes per day FREE with Cloud Build (shared across the entire organisation, it's not a free tier per project!). You can run up to 10 build jobs in parallel.
- Use AI Platform training. Similarly to Cloud Build, [AI Platform training allows you to run a custom container for performing processing](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training), initially think for training. But, it's a container, you can run whatever you want in it. No free tier here. You are limited to 20 CPU in parallel but you can ask for increasing the limit up to 450 concurrent vCPU.

Sadly, it's not as easy as a Function or a Cloud Run to use. You don't have an HTTP endpoint and you simply call this with the date that you want and enjoy. But you can wrap this into a function which perform the API calls to the Cloud Build or the AI Platform training.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. With any of those workarounds, would I get a dashboard to see the progress of my jobs?

Comment: For seeing what's happen, I recommend you to log things and to use stackdriver logging to view them.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, with Google Cloud Functions you can configure the timeout for up to 9 minutes during the deployment.

Solutions different to Dataflow that allow higher timeouts:

**App engine Flex**

Other GCP product that allows higher timeouts (up to 60 minutes) is the App Engine Flex environment [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features).

**Cloud Tasks**

Cloud tasks is also similar, but asynchronous. With timeouts up to 30 min. It is a task queue, you put the task in the queue and returns quickly. Then, the worker (or workers) of the queue will evaluate the tasks one by one.
The usual output of Cloud Tasks is to send emails or to save the results into a Storage [link](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#handler).

With this solution, you can add a task for each file/filename to process and each of this tasks has the timeout of 30 min.